# Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2012

We will migrate from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012. 
My question is if we can use Team Foundation Server 2010 on the new server, or if we need to update to TFS 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Sharepoint Foundation 2010 doesn't support Windows Server 2012, and I believe SQL 2012 doesn't work with TFS 2010, but if you can live without Sharepoint and you can use SQL 2008 R2 (or prior), you should be fine.

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592.aspx

Notice where it says:

Because Team Foundation Server installs SharePoint Foundation 2010 with the standard configuration, you can’t use it on Windows Server 2012. If you want to install Team Foundation Server on Windows Server 2012, use the advanced configuration and skip the installation of SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Regarding SQL 2012, take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/11/tfs-2010-will-not-support-sql-2012.aspx

Comment: The reasons for lacking SQL Server 2012 support are very unclear. Brian did not state what T-SQL dependencies there were that break for example - just vague assertions about Workflows and missing SQL Server 2012 feature support (which is irrelevant anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get TFS 2010 running on Windows Server 2012 because TFS doesn't seem to recognize the IIS 6.0 compatibility mode.  See:

[Error installing TFS 2010 in Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206380/error-installing-tfs-2010-in-windows-server-2012)

and

[Application Tier Configuration Failed For TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2012 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040827/application-tier-configuration-failed-for-tfs-2010-on-windows-server-2012-r2)

Magol and Adam (or anyone else), have you got it running successfully?

Comment: I never tried. I chose to upgrade to TFS 2012 instead

Comment: In the end, we installed TFS 2012 as well.  Full migration of all TFS 2010 collections to TFS 2012 is not done yet, working well so far.