# Error installing TFS 2010 in Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

When I try to install Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows Server 2012, It get following errors:

- Error    [ Application Tier ] TF255120: Compatibility mode for Internet
  Information Services (IIS) 6.0 is not enabled. Team Foundation Server
  requires this on this operating system.
- Error    [ Application Tier ]
  TF255456: You must configure Internet Information Services (IIS) to
  use the Static Content component. Team Foundation Server requires the
  Static Content component in IIS.
- Error    [ Application Tier ] TF255397:
  Windows Authentication has not been configured as a role service in
  Internet Information Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires
  that Windows Authentication is installed as one of the role services
  in IIS.
- Error    [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication
  has not been configured as a role service in Internet Information
  Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows
  Authentication is installed as one of the role services in IIS.
- Error    [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication has not
  been configured as a role service in Internet Information Services
  (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows Authentication is
  installed as one of the role services in IIS.

I cant found the settings in ISS

Comment: This is considered "off-topic" for stack overflow. But I don't think it is supported, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I concur - don't think TFS2010 is supported yet on Windows Server 2012. Just tried to do the same in the lab