# Application Tier Configuration Failed For TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, iis-8, azure-devops

I have installed TFS for Visual studio 2010 on Windows Server 2012R2. ISS is already configured with IIS 6 compatibility, Static content compression and Windows authentication. But the application tier configuration failed with the following errors

```
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255120: Compatibility mode for Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 is not enabled. Team Foundation Server requires this on this operating system.
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255456: You must configure Internet Information Services (IIS) to use the Static Content component. Team Foundation Server requires the Static Content component in IIS.
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication has not been configured as a role service in Internet Information Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows Authentication is installed as one of the role services in IIS.
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication has not been configured as a role service in Internet Information Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows Authentication is installed as one of the role services in IIS.
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication has not been configured as a role service in Internet Information Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows Authentication is installed as one of the role services in IIS.
```

I configured the IIS as in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for IIS8 (Win8 and 2012Svr use) was added in TFS2012.  (TFS2012 calls dism with the proper feature list instead of pkgmgr).  [IIS8 shipped after TFS2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6942cd0a-55d7-44f8-bfda-4c450c3bb7a5/tfs-2010-on-windows-8-challenge?forum=tfsgeneral).

It's available for download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38185)

Also consider using cloud TFS.  It's free and avoids stuff like this:  http://www.visualstudio.com/

If that's not an option and it's critical, I believe it can be hacked around.  Contact me offline if that's the case (I wrote the code to make it work with IIS8).  But, I still recommend TFS 2012 server :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I'm using visual studio 2010 and Visual source safe for my projects. I  want to migrate to TFS. Is it possible to use TFS2012 with VS2010?

Comment: TFS 2012 actually has a source safe migration wizard in it.  Go into the admin console after installing it and there's a link to install it.  VS2010 works fine against TFS2012.

Comment: Thank you bryanmac. I will download and try TFS2012

Comment: can you share the code for making TFS 2010 works on win2012?